# Who is the seiyuu of Aya in Mushishi?

Tags: voice-acting, mushishi

Who is the seiyuu/voice actress of the young Aya in Episode 17 of Mushishi? I want to know because I think she sounds like Naru Kotoishi from *Barakamon*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: 綺（子供時代） 黒葛原未有]

[Tsuzurahara Miyu](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=25483), apparently.

Incidentally, AnimeNewsNetwork tends to have very comprehensive listings of voice actors and staff, so that's always a good place to check if you have a question like this in the future.